# Flutter nested Rows MainAxisAlignment

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to do this :

[image: website display]

But here is what I actually got :

[image: mobile display]

Here is my code :

```
Row itemTransaction(BuildContext context, Transaction transaction) {
  /// This is the function that will build each item of our transaction list.
  return new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
        child: new Image.asset(
          (transaction.sent) ? "images/tx_output.png" : "images/tx_input.png",
        ),
      ),
      new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              discoderyText("test"),
              discoderyText("test 2"),
            ],
          ),
          discoderyText("SOME HASH KEY"),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

The `discoderyText` is basically a custom text (i.e. with colors).

As you can see, there is `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` set for my Row, so `test` and `test2` **should** be on **opposite sides**.

When I remove the image and I only returns a `Row` that contains two `Text`, and I set the `mainAxisAlignment`, it works. It seems like **nested rows can NOT use this variable**.

Here is basically the plan of my view :

[image: Layout plan]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Screenshot**

[image]

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
      child: CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: AssetImage(chocolateImage),),
    ),
    Expanded( // add this
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0), // give some padding
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // set it to min
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("test"),
                Text("test 2"),
              ],
            ),
            Text("SOME HASH KEY HERE"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks to the Expanded widget, thank you very much !  
However, it seems like mainAxisSize and the column MainAxisAlignment are useless (if I set it to different values, or if I simply delete them, it provides no changes on my view).  
So what are their purposes here ?

Comment: `mainAxisSize` would only matter if you are not providing fixed constraints to your parent `Row`. And `mainAxisAlignment` makes all the images, text right there in the middle of the `Row`.