# How can I make a design like in the photo in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[exchange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH1Sk.jpg)

I want to add in my project this. How can i do something like that or similar?

Answer (score 0):

U can use row widgets for this and nest them 
Row(
Row()
Row()
)
Use listview builder to display all the set of rows
Eg question [Flutter nested Rows MainAxisAlignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873091/flutter-nested-rows-mainaxisalignment)